# Possible to dispatch an action without connect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

```
export default class App extends Component {
...
  componentDidMount() {
    //registering event listener
    BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', this.onLocation, this.onError);
  }

  onLocation(location) {
   //wishing to dispatch an action to update variable in store
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider>
          <MainNavigator screenProps={{ isConnected: this.state.isConnected }} />
        </AlertProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

From what I understand, I can't possibly connect to store in this component as we are just configuring and pass the store into Provider. How would i possibly dispatch an action in my `onLocation` event?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can directly dispatch using the store object.

```
store.dispatch({type:"UPDATE_VARIABLE", payload:variable.value})
```

If you are in some other component where the store object isnt readily available, export it from the main component and import it to a location where it is needed and use the above statement

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Comment: Where do you import "store" from?

Comment: @Renoldus from `'/redux-store'`

Comment: Where ever you've defined the rootreducer or combineReducers wrapper, import the exported store from this file.

Answer (score 3):

**react-redux** has own hooks to call them

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const state = useSelector((state) => state);
```

do not forget to import them

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
```

vs code will autocomplete if you write useDispatch

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and add the constructor in the class like this

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onLocation() {
    this.props.dispatch({type: GET_THINGS_REQUESTED, payload: value});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UmiJS 3.x**  users can do:

```
import { getDvaApp } from 'umi';

const dispatch = getDvaApp()._store.dispatch;

dispatch({ … })
```